# Libgmp NDK Build issue with x86_64

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, cross-compiling, gmp

I am trying to build libgmp with NDK as static (shared also doesn't work), I need this to link with nettle and gnutls. The versions I am using below:

- GMP: 6.1.2
- NDK: r16b
- Target: x86_64
- API: android-27
- Env: Ubuntu 16.04 (Windows shell)

So I download a tar of libgmp from their website and then the android standalong toolchain:

```
$NDK/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch "x86_64" --api 27 \
     --stl=libc++ --install-dir /tmp/android-toolchain --force
```

Set the environment to link with NDK

```
     # Prefix is out the output folder location
     PREBUILT=/tmp/android-toolchain
     CROSS_COMPILE=$PREBUILT/bin/x86_64-
     CFLAGS="-isystem /tmp/android-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64/ -D__ANDROID_API__=27-I$PREFIX/include"

    export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=/tmp/android-toolchain/sysroot/usr/lib -L$/tmp/android-toolchain/sysroot/usr/lib -lc -lm -ldl -llog -nostdlib -lgcc -L$PREFIX/lib"
    export CPPFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CXX="clang++"
    export AS="clang"
    export CC="clang" 
    export NM="${CROSS_COMPILE}nm"
    export STRIP="${CROSS_COMPILE}strip"
    export RANLIB="${CROSS_COMPILE}ranlib"
    export AR="${CROSS_COMPILE}ar"
    export LD="${CROSS_COMPILE}ld"
```

then ran configure

```
./configure 
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --host="x86_64-linux" \
    --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
    --disable-dependency-tracking \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-shared \
    || exit 1

 make -j4 || exit 1
```

Prefix points to output directory, (also tried host x86_64-linux-android). It configures but then after that when running make, it will try to compile a bunch of binaries that auto create a bunch of files such as **gen-fib.c** -> **gen-fib** binary.

Makefile then runs that binary to create the header file (**fib_table.h**) and the source fib_table.c. When Makefile runs (I believe something like)

```
gen-fib header <number> <number> > fib_table.h
```

It outputs nothing, so **fib_table.h** is empty (0 bytes). I tried to run it from command line and nothing appears. Tried to create a file in **gen-fib.c** and have it compiled to create a dummy file and nothing happens. The binary executes nothing, does not run at all!

Now I have compiled this successfully with arm64 (aarch64 or arm64-v8a) and x86 (and of course ran *make distclean* between different hosts). I tried to compare the config.log with x86 and x86_64 which the only difference being the host argument in the configure and x86 android toolchain. For my x86_64 log file you can read that here: 
https://pastebin.com/LLEbDz11

If anyone knows why the binaries (like gen-fibs) do not run after compiling them for x86_64 (but other abi like x86 and arm64) please let me know.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the binaries were not building because it was using the toolchain's clang. Using

```
 export CC_FOR_BUILD=/usr/bin/gcc
```

Uses the gcc from linux to compile it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## Prehistory

I need this library for another library.
I found some examples and used them.
I'm not sure about all the flags, but this works for me.

Be careful.

## Building gmp-6.2.1 by using Android NDK

### Links

Source:
https://gmplib.org/

Build Options:
https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options

Android NDK Params example:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems

Configuration Reference:
[Libgmp NDK Build issue with x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518335/libgmp-ndk-build-issue-with-x86-64)

Bug in Android ARM 32-bit build with assembly allowed:
https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-bugs/2020-April/004767.html

### Info

Build System: "Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS"

Target System: "aarch64-linux-android30"

Packages Require: m4 (apt install m4)

### Build

```
# Run this script from: <path_to_gmp>/_build


# Build machine
NDK=<path_to_ndk>/android-ndk-r22b
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

# Target device
TARGET=aarch64-linux-android
TARGET_LIB=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/lib/$TARGET


PREFIX=<path_to_gmp>/_result

# minSdkVersion
export API=30

export CFLAGS="-isystem ${TOOLCHAIN}/sysroot/usr/include/${TARGET} -DANDROID_API=$API -I$PREFIX/include"
export CPPFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
export CXXFLAGS="-fPIE -std=c++14 -DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DAPP_STL=c++_static --target=${TARGET}${API} -static-libstdc++"
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-pie"



export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
export CXX=$CC++


CROSS_COMPILE=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-

export AS=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-as
export LD=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/ld.lld
export AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar
export NM=${CROSS_COMPILE}nm
export STRIP=${CROSS_COMPILE}strip
export RANLIB=${CROSS_COMPILE}ranlib




# Configure params
#    Had some problem with assembly,
#    Try it first without '--disable-assembly'.

../configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --host="x86_64-linux" \
    --build=$TARGET$API \
    --enable-cxx \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-shared \
    --disable-assembly \
    || exit 1


# Build
make 
make install
```